# Neural Net Back-propagation: Question on Wikipedia math

Tags: neural-networks

I'm reading the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) article on Backpropagation and have some questions on the math.

$$
\frac{d C}{d a^L}\cdot \frac{d a^L}{d z^L} \cdot \frac{d z^L}{d a^{L-1}} \cdot \frac{d a^{L-1}}{d z^{L-1}}\cdot \frac{d z^{L-1}}{d a^{L-2}} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{d a^1}{d z^1} \cdot \frac{\partial z^1}{\partial x}
$$

where $z^l = (f^l)'$, $f^l$ is the activation function and $a^l$ is the activation.

Questions:

1. With ${d z^l}$ what are we looking at the change of the change of the activation function?
2. Is $a^l$ the same as $f^l$?

Thanks